# Logged as root but still asking me to run as administrator

Tags: windows

I am logging as administrator to my computer it is windows7 os(actually it has only one account)

but why some programs are still need to be run as administrator

Eg: host file

1.why it is asking

2.logging with root account is just for logging purpose

Answer (score 0):

Ever since Windows Vista Microsoft introduced User Access Control. This has a completely different security model than Windows XP. Applications run at a user level with the exception of Internet Explorer which runs at 100, even lower than user level. This is to prevent malicious software having full run of your system should your PC become infected.

When logged in as admin, you will be asked to elevate the application permissions. You will not be prompted for credentials. A user logged in (not admin) would be prompted for credentials.